# Out of Memory Exception

Tags: vb.net, memory, desktop

I have developed desktop application in VB.NET. Framework is 3.5 And back end as SQL Server 2005.

Below is the code[To release the memory when form closed] which i had write in master form, from which all the forms are inherited.

```
  Private Declare Auto Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal procHandle As IntPtr, ByVal min As Int32, ByVal max As Int32) As Boolean
Private Declare Function EmptyWorkingSet Lib "psapi.dll" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr) As Long

Private Sub frmEMR_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(GC.GetTotalMemory(True))
    EmptyWorkingSet(Process.GetCurrentProcess.Handle)
    SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess.Handle, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

Though i had write this heap memory contentious increasing.

Also the un-managed memory increasing.

Can any one help me out from this.

Thanks & Regards

Hemal shah

Answer (score 1):

My first rule when dealing with memory leaks, go through all the code and make sure that if the object has a `dispose()` method to use it. Not knowing what your application is doing, I can only guess, but I do know that many of .NET SQL objects have `dispose()` and `close()` functions. If your app uses a lot of these then you might have forgotten to dispose of them.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i want to write something generalize so i can write in master form and work for all inherited form.

Comment: Usually the best practice is dispose as soon as you are done with it. This way you don't run the risk of out of memory errors. Basically your application is creating all these instances, and uses the memory, and the memory doesn't get freed until you close the form. Where as if you dispose as soon as you are done then the memory is made available for the next command.

Answer (score 1):

There's [no point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in calling `EmptyWorkingSet` if you call `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` with `-1, -1` later, since this will also empty the working set.

Also I don't understand why you are calling `RemoveMemoryPressure` with the return value of `GetTotalMemory`. This doesn't make any sense...

My advide is:

- Don't mess around with garbage collection (if you don't know what you are doing). The garbage collector will do it for you.

If you're running out of memory, you probably have a memory leak. You won't fix it by randomly calling functions that you don't understand.

I bet your problem is caused by not handling unmanaged ressources correctly, and I also bet you're using classes of the framework that implement `IDisposable` and you're not disposing them (by either calling `Dispose` or using the `using` keyword).

Ensure to dispose all of those objects. If the problem still exists, use a [memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to find the cause of your memory leak.

There is no silver bullet method you can call that will magically fix your bugs.

Also have a look at the numerous questions of the same topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am already using ANTS Memory Profiler. From this I show the unmanaged memory and Heap storage are increasing and get the memroy exception